# Serverless Framework dry run or test without deploying

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, infrastructure

There's any way to test Serverless Framework code without deploying it? Similar to Terraform's dry run.

I've tried using the `--noDeploy` flag, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to create a CI pipeline for it, but can't find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

the closest we have in Serverless Framework is the `serverless package` command, it will build and save all of the deployment artifacts in the `.serverless` directory:

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/

you can inspect the CloudFormation and anything else (e.g. code transpilation, plugins etc) generated by Serverless Framework in that folder